# Validation Binding on First Load

Tags: wpf, validation, binding

I'm still struggling with validation in WPF.

I've got a custom validation rule which requires text to appear in a textbox i.e. it enforces a mandatory field constraint.

```
<TextBox local:Masking.Mask="^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" x:Name="CameraIdCodeTextBox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
  <Binding Path="CameraIdCode" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnValidationError="True" ValidatesOnExceptions="True">
    <Binding.ValidationRules>
      <localValidation:RequiredFieldRule />
    </Binding.ValidationRules>
  </Binding>
</TextBox>
```

The problem is, that when the Window first loads, there is no text in the TextBox (as you would expect). But the Text property is being bound to a property on the ViewModel, and as such, the validation Rule is firing, indicating that there is a problem with the Window - before the user has even had an opportunity to violate a business rule.

Is this a problem which has been solved before? I can't have been the 1st to experience this. I'm sure it is a trap for young players.

Comment: Can you try ... UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus"

Comment: You may be able to create a validation group, and only enable it, when user first makes a change to some field.

Comment: @AngelWPF I have tried that. It still validates on the initial bind when the window loads.

Comment: @VladimirPerevalov Is it possible to enable and disable bindings? If it was, I should probably just disable the binding on first load. But how do I enable it? Capturing the logic of a users first change, as distinct from every future change soulds quite complicated. I'm not sure why a simple RequiredField validator is so difficult.

Comment: You may need to move validation to the set; as set does not get called on initial binding.  Or possibly allow string.empty in the validation but reject string.empty in the set; (and throw a validation error).

Comment: I agree with @Blam, putting validation in the setters seem to work the best... now you might need to set the properties though code, which will force validation, but there are ways around that

Comment: It may be useful  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502263/how-to-suppress-validation-when-nothing-is-entered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while and I should have updated this question. I resolved it using a class which I found in a WPF book by Ian Griffths (an O'Reilly book):

```
public static class Validator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This method forces WPF to validate the child controls of the control passed in as a parameter.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parent">Type: DependencyObject. The control which is the descendent root control to validate.</param>
    /// <returns>Type: bool. The validation result</returns>
    public static bool IsValid(DependencyObject parent)
    {
        // Validate all the bindings on the parent
        bool valid = true;
        LocalValueEnumerator localValues = parent.GetLocalValueEnumerator();
        while (localValues.MoveNext())
        {
            LocalValueEntry entry = localValues.Current;
            if (BindingOperations.IsDataBound(parent, entry.Property))
            {
                Binding binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(parent, entry.Property);
                foreach (ValidationRule rule in binding.ValidationRules)
                {
                    ValidationResult result = rule.Validate(parent.GetValue(entry.Property), null);
                    if (!result.IsValid)
                    {
                        BindingExpression expression = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(parent, entry.Property);
                        Validation.MarkInvalid(expression, new ValidationError(rule, expression, result.ErrorContent, null));
                        valid = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Validate all the bindings on the children
        for (int i = 0; i != VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); ++i)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            if (!IsValid(child))
            {
                valid = false;
            }
        }

        return valid;
    }

}
```

Then, on the view, I had the following configuration:

```
<TextBox local:Masking.Mask="^[0-9]*$" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=LocationNumberEnabled}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3">
    <Binding Path="LocationNumber"  Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus" NotifyOnValidationError="True" ValidatesOnExceptions="True">
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <localValidation:PositiveNumberRule />
            <localValidation:RequiredFieldRule />
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>                    
</TextBox>
```

Worked like a charm! I just called the IsValid method every time I wanted to manually validate e.g. on a button press.

Comment: The C# and XAML code do not seem to interact with each other. How and where are you supposed to use `Validator.IsValid`?

Comment: I no longer have the code for this, but as memory serves, in the button press, you pass in the parent. Was something like `Validator.IsValid(grid)`.

Comment: I see, so you have to trigger this on the source-side. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of patterns for this.  I usually implement on the class/Model the `ISupportInitialize` interface, which will require you creating `BeginInit()` and `EndInit()` in those methods I simply set a private bool `_isInitializing` to true or false.

In the view model or where/when you create/populate your model/class wrap it with begin and end init:

```
var o = new SampleObject();
o.BeginInit()
o.StartDate = DateTime.Now; //just some sample property...
o.EndInit();
```

So then depending how your ValidationRule is invoked, you could check the state of your `_isInitializing` to see if you need to validate.

Lately I've been using attribute validators which fire on `PropertyChanged` so you could do something like:

```
[CustomValidator("ValidateStartDate")]
 public DateTime StartDate
 { get ...
 {
   set
     {
       if(_startDate == value) return;
       _startDate = value;
       if(_isInitializing) return;
       RaisePropertyChange(() => StartDate);
      }..
```

If you don't want to bother with `ISupportInitialize`, then pass all the values that you need in your properties during construction not the property. Binding will query the getters on you properties first time and will get their values, and after anything will go through property setter and get validated:

```
 //c-tor
 public MyObject(DateTime start)
 {
    _startDate = start;
 }
```