# Disable validation onload and implement INotifyPropertyChanged on property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm writing a WPF application with a MVVM approach, and I am using IDataErrorInfo for error validation. 
When I load the View, the validation is checked without changing the content of the TextBox, I solved the issue by following .

[How to suppress validation when nothing is entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502263/how-to-suppress-validation-when-nothing-is-entered)

But now the problem is I can't implement INotifyPropertyChanged when there is a change in the textbox.

So basically my tool has a start button, textbox and end button. The application do the following

```
1) The start button onclick start a timer and disable the start button
2) User provide data in textbox
3) End the timer and calulate time difference. enable the start button for the next entry.
4) The problem is here the textbox data is not refreshed while I click the startbutton again. Since the onpropertychanged is not set on the property I can't able to refresh the data.
```

I can able to resolve the refresh textbox issue through implementing onpropertychange but the onload error is shown while I load the data.

so what i want is I want to disable the onload validation and also refresh the content after completing the process.

Window.xaml

```
  <Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsStartButtonEnabled}" Width="79" Height="19" Margin="-700,1,708.962,0" x:Name="startbutton" Command="{Binding AddNew}" Content="Start Time"/>
  <Label Width="61" Height="24" Margin="-700,1,708.962,0" x:Name="StartTimeLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Start Time"/>
  <TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding Isdisabled}" x:Name="StarttimeTextbox" Width="71" Height="24" Margin="-700,1,708.962,0" Text="{Binding ClaimNumber, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"/>
   <Button Command="{Binding stop }"  Margin="500,0,0,0" Width="70" Height="20"  VerticalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabledSubmit}" Content="Submit"/>
```

ViewModel.cs

```
private bool nameChanged = false;
private string claimnumber;

    public string ClaimNumber
    {
        get { return this.claimnumber; }
        set
        {
            this.claimnumber = value;
            nameChanged = true;
 //I have disabled the onpropertychanged because if I uncommented I can 
 //able to accomplish textbox refresh but the tool throws error when i 
 //load the data
            // this.OnPropertyChanged("ClaimNumber");
        }
    }

AddNew = new RelayCommand(o => startbutton());
stop = new RelayCommand(o => stopbutton());

public void startbutton()
    {
     //The claimnumber should be empty whenever I click the startbutton 
        ClaimNumber = null;
        stopWatch.Start();
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
        IsEnabled = true;
        IsStartButtonEnabled = false;

    }
public void stopbutton()
    {

            stopWatch.Stop();
            TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
            string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}",
                    ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
            IsEnabled = false;
    }

  private string GetValidationError(string propertyName)
      {
        string errorMsg = null;

        switch (propertyName)
        {
            case "ClaimNumber":
                if ((nameChanged && propertyName.Equals("ClaimNumber")))
                {
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.claimnumber))

                        errorMsg = "Please provide the claimnumber";
                    else if (CheckInteger(claimnumber) == false)
                        errorMsg = "The given claimnumberis not a Number";

                }

                break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the namechanged boolean to false on stopbutton rather than on the startbutton.

So below are the issues I faced are solved now,

1) The application will throw error on application loading which has been resolved by removal of onproperty change in property.

2) Used boolean namechanged instead of onpropertychaned. whenever the property has been invoked and used the boolean to trigger the error.

3) In the stop button made all the property to null and there I have used onpropertytochanged to reflect the changes i have performed in the modelview.

```
private bool nameChanged = false;
private string claimnumber;

public string ClaimNumber
{
    get { return this.claimnumber; }
    set
    {
        this.claimnumber = value;
        nameChanged = true;

    }
}

AddNew = new RelayCommand(o => startbutton());
stop = new RelayCommand(o => stopbutton());

public void startbutton()
{

    stopWatch.Start();
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
    IsEnabled = true;
    IsStartButtonEnabled = false;

}
public void stopbutton()
{

        stopWatch.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}",
                ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
        IsEnabled = false;
  //The claimnumber made empty whenever i click end the button
        ClaimNumber = null;
 // Here i made the boolean to false so the error message will not be triggered.
        nameChanged = false;
 // Now the claimnumber which i emptied above should be reflected in the view
        this.onPropertyChanged("Clainumber");
}

   private string GetValidationError(string propertyName)
  {
    string errorMsg = null;

    switch (propertyName)
    {
        case "ClaimNumber":
            if ((nameChanged && propertyName.Equals("ClaimNumber")))
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.claimnumber))

                    errorMsg = "Please provide the claimnumber";
                else if (CheckInteger(claimnumber) == false)
                    errorMsg = "The given claimnumberis not a Number";

            }

            break;
}
}
```